# Rectangle in sdl2 sets colour for entire screen

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I know there are already questions like this on SO but I am new to SDL2 and I have had a look at some tutorials to draw a rectangle and I have had a look at some questions here as well. With the current code below I cannot draw a rectanlge onto the window as it doesn't appear I have also tried to clear the window after the rectangle is meant to be drawn this just sets the entire window to that colour.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2\SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    SDL_Window* window;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* render;
    render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    bool close = false;
    SDL_Event event;
    while (close == false){
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                close = true;
            }
        }

        //set colour
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(render, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(render);

        SDL_Rect rect;
        rect.x, rect.y, rect.h, rect.w = 50, 50, 50, 50;
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(render, 0, 0, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(render, &rect);
        //SDL_RenderClear(render); <-- If this is uncommented it clears the screen to blue.
        SDL_RenderPresent(render);
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(render);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

This is mean't to draw a blue rectangle onto a red window but I only get the red window and clearing the renderer only set's the window blue. Why does this rectangle not draw? If it is drawing then how come the colour of it ahsnt changed so it doesn't blend in with the background.

I have used these questions to help me get this far:
[How to draw a rectangle in SDL 2 and what exactly is a renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326459/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-in-sdl-2-and-what-exactly-is-a-renderer)
[SDL2 Wont draw Rectangles Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52490937/sdl2-wont-draw-rectangles-correctly)
https://dev.to/noah11012/using-sdl2-drawing-rectangles-3hc2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue seems to be with the `rect.x, rect.y, rect.h, rect.w = 50, 50, 50, 50;`

When I changed it to

```
 rect.x = 50;
 rect.y = 50;
 rect.h = 50;
 rect.w = 50;
```

The program worked

Comment: you can also write it as 
`rect.x = 50, rect.y = 50, rect.h = 50, rect.w = 50;`
or 
`SDL_Rect rect{50, 50, 50, 50};`